# Mostrar tag de lançamento quando data for IS NOT NULL

Tags: php

Estou tentando fazer uma exibição de uma tag de lançamento e o que parecia ser simples acabou se tornando uma complicação.
O cadastro de produto tem dois campos, `data_inicial` e `data_expiração`, inicialmente faço um `select` para mostrar todos os produtos, depois estou fazendo um outro select para pegar os produtos que estejam com as datas preenchidas, no caso, `IS NOT NULL` e tento mostrar a tag que é uma imagem, vou tentar não complicar.

O primeiro `select` que pega todos os produtos de acordo com as cláusulas definidas, o mesmo está assim:

```
mysql_select_db($database_conexao, $conexao);
if ($IdCategoria != 0) {
    $query_rsProdutos = "SELECT 
                              produtos_imagem.caminho,
                              produtos_imagem.caminho_thumbs,
                              produtos.codigo_iabv,
                              produtos.nome,
                              produtos.lancamento,
                              produtos.id_produto                                                         
                            FROM
                              categorias
                              INNER JOIN produtos ON (categorias.id_categoria = produtos.id_categoria)
                              INNER JOIN produtos_imagem ON (produtos.id_produto = produtos_imagem.id_produto)
                            WHERE
                              (produtos.id_produto = produtos_imagem.id_produto) AND 
                              (produtos.id_categoria = '".$IdCategoria."') AND 
                              (produtos.id_idioma = '".$_SESSION['idioma']."') AND
                              (produtos.`status` = 1)";
} else {
    $query_rsProdutos = "SELECT 
                              produtos_imagem.caminho,
                              produtos_imagem.caminho_thumbs,
                              produtos.codigo_iabv,
                              produtos.nome,
                              produtos.lancamento,
                              produtos.id_produto
                            FROM
                              categorias
                              INNER JOIN produtos ON (categorias.id_categoria = produtos.id_categoria)
                              INNER JOIN produtos_imagem ON (produtos.id_produto = produtos_imagem.id_produto)
                            WHERE
                              (produtos.id_produto = produtos_imagem.id_produto) AND                              
                              (produtos.id_idioma = '".$_SESSION['idioma']."') AND
                              (produtos.`status` = 1)"; 
}
$rsProdutos = mysql_query($query_rsProdutos, $conexao) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rsProdutos = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsProdutos);
$totalRows_rsProdutos = mysql_num_rows($rsProdutos);
```

Isso me mostra todos os produtos, estou exibindo todos assim:

```html
<?php do { 

mysql_select_db($database_conexao, $conexao);
$query_rsProdutosLanc = 
 "SELECT         
   produtos.data_inicial,
   produtos.data_expiracao
 FROM
   produtos
 WHERE        
   (produtos.id_idioma = '".$_SESSION['idioma']."') AND         
   (produtos.`status` = 1) AND
   (produtos.data_inicial IS NOT NULL) AND
   (produtos.data_expiracao IS NOT NULL)";    
$rsProdutosLanc = mysql_query($query_rsProdutosLanc, $conexao) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rsProdutosLanc = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsProdutosLanc); 

$DataInicial = $row_rsProdutosLanc['data_inicial'];       
$DataExpiracao = $row_rsProdutosLanc['data_expiracao']; 

?>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4"> <a class="shop-item-list" href="detalhes.php?id=<?php echo $row_rsProdutos['id_produto'];  ?>">

<figure> 
 <?php if ($DataInicial <= $DataExpiracao) { ?>
 <div class="imagem-mascara"></div>
 <?php } ?>                
 <img  src="<?php echo $row_rsProdutos['caminho']; ?>" alt="" />
</figure>


<div class="product-info">
  <h2> <span class="product-name"> <span class="bold">CÓD.: </span><?php echo utf8_encode($row_rsProdutos['codigo_iabv']); ?></span> <span class="product-name"><?php echo utf8_encode($row_rsProdutos['nome']); ?></span> </h2>
</div>
</a>
</div>

<?php } while($row_rsProdutos = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsProdutos)); ?>
```

Dentro do loop para mostrar os produtos estou fazendo um novo `select` para tentar pegar as datas `IS NOT NULL` para mostrar a `tag` de lançamento.

A `tag` estou tentando mostrar assim dentro desse `loop`:

```html
<figure> 
 <?php if ($DataInicial <= $DataExpiracao) { ?>
 <div class="imagem-mascara"></div>
 <?php } ?>                
 <img  src="<?php echo $row_rsProdutos['caminho']; ?>" alt="" />
</figure>
```

Mas a tag está aparecendo em todos os produtos.

As datas estão nesse formato:

```
data_inicial - 2017-10-01
data_expiracao - 2017-10-31
```

Até fiz uma tentativa com isso, mas mesmo assim não resolveu;

```html
<?php if (strtotime($DataInicial) <= strtotime($DataExpiracao)) { ?> 
    <div class="imagem-mascara"></div> 
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: dá um exemplo de `$DataInicial` e respectiva `$DataExpiracao`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui resolver o meu problema, descartei o segundo `loop`, inseri as datas no primeiro `select` e agora único `select`, depois fiz algumas verificações antes de mostrar ou não a `tag` de lançamento, ficou assim:

Dentro do `loop`:

```
if ($row_rsProdutos['data_inicial'] == "" and $row_rsProdutos['data_expiracao'] == "") {
    $Lanc = 0;
} else {
   if ($row_rsProdutos['data_inicial'] = date('Y-m-d')) {
       $Lanc = 1;
   } else {
       $Lanc = 0;
   }
}
```

E para mostrar ou não a imagem fiz assim:

```html
<?php if ($Lanc == 1) { ?> 
  <div class="imagem-mascara"></div>
<?php  } ?>
```

Agradeço as dicas repassadas.

Answer (score 0):

Como você está comparando data o ideal seria converter ela para `strtotime`, ai a comparação é mais precisa, mas se desejar também pode fazer o banco no caso o mysql retornar para você a diferença de dias entre datas com `DATEDIFF(data_inicial, data_expiracao)` vai retornar positivo ou negativo dependendo da ordem usada, se "0" é a mesma data, ai basta você adicionar a tua select:

```
SELECT produtos.data_inicial, produtos.data_expiracao,
DATEDIFF(produtos.data_inicial, produtos.data_expiracao) dif
```

E comparar no php.